# Selenium Chromedriver closes without Error, but with StackTrace?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying automate some of my processes through python selenium, but my program ends unexpectedly without error message. Since most of my codes are wrapped with try / except and waits until the element is present (or clickable), I really don't think this would be error related to no element present.

This is my python3 code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import random
import re
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps) 

warningstring = ""
pagenum = 1
driver.get("url")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/form/input[1]'))
).send_keys("email")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/form/input[2]'))
).send_keys("password")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/form/button'))
).click()
while True: 
    for i in range(1, 25):
        try: 
            driver.get(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/ul/li[{0}]/div[2]/div[1]/a'.format(i)))
            ).get_attribute("href"))
            dabangfloor = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li[2]/div[2]'))
            ).text.split("/")[1].replace("층","")
            dabangpark = re.findall(r'\d+', WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li[7]/div[2]'))
            ).text)[0]
            dabangpurpose = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li[9]/div[2]/p'))
            ).text 
            print(i, dabangfloor, dabangpark, dabangpurpose)
            driver.get("url".format(pagenum))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print(warningstring)
            exit(0)
    try:
        pagenum += 1
    except Exception as clicke: 
        print(clicke)
        print("End of the page, done.")
        print(warningstring)
        exit(0)
k = input("Press Any Key")
```

This is output of console when it unexpectedly ends.

```
Message: 
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x0000000102601670 chromedriver + 4298352
1   chromedriver                        0x00000001025f9bbc chromedriver + 4266940
2   chromedriver                        0x000000010222c758 chromedriver + 280408
3   chromedriver                        0x0000000102267b38 chromedriver + 523064
4   chromedriver                        0x00000001022a0080 chromedriver + 753792
5   chromedriver                        0x000000010225a2d0 chromedriver + 467664
6   chromedriver                        0x000000010225b354 chromedriver + 471892
7   chromedriver                        0x00000001025c16c4 chromedriver + 4036292
8   chromedriver                        0x00000001025c5c64 chromedriver + 4054116
9   chromedriver                        0x00000001025cc2d8 chromedriver + 4080344
10  chromedriver                        0x00000001025c6970 chromedriver + 4057456
11  chromedriver                        0x000000010259d8dc chromedriver + 3889372
12  chromedriver                        0x00000001025e525c chromedriver + 4182620
13  chromedriver                        0x00000001025e53b4 chromedriver + 4182964
14  chromedriver                        0x00000001025f40f4 chromedriver + 4243700
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000019898206c _pthread_start + 148
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000019897ce2c thread_start + 8
```

I really have no idea where to start, since no one near me or internet seems to know the cause.
I tried wrapping all my codes with try except and use more time.sleep for website to fully load.

Comment: can you please mention the URL you're targeting in order to reproduce the issue and provide the solution? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: At which line do you face the error? Update the question with the complete error stacktrace.

Comment: Hi, that is literally the complete error stacktrace that I see on my visual studio code. Unfortunately, the url is authorized login only... so I wonder if sharing html / css / js code of website would help.

Comment: maybe it's chromedriver and chrome version mismatch